# Jquery Mobile panel dynamic listview does not render correctly

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a searchresults.php page which shows several users that have been found. Also on the searchresults.php page is a panel

```html
<div data-role="panel" id="mypanel" data-display="overlay" data-theme="a">
  <div id="loadedprofile">
  </div>
</div><!-- /panel -->
```

When I click on one of the "user divs" the following Jquery function fires to open the panel:

a panel on select of a search result.

The JQuery code:

```js
$('[id=profile]').on("click", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var userid = $(this).attr('userid');
    //window.location.href = "userdetails.php?userid=" + userid;

    $("#mypanel").panel("open");
    $("#loadedprofile").load("userdetailspanel.php?userid=" + userid);

    $("#mypanel").trigger("updatelayout");

    $('#commandlist').listview('refresh');

    $('[data-role=page]').trigger('pagecreate');
    $.mobile.activePage.trigger('pagecreate');

    $('#commandlist').listview().listview('refresh');

});
```

Ok, so the panel opens up correctly and the dynamic page (userdetailspanel.php) is loaded correctly (see image). But ALSO on the userdetailspanel.php is a listview.

```html
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="commandlist">
 <li>
  <a href="#" id="mylink" name="mylink" >
    <img src='bolt.png' class="ui-li-icon" />Link
  </a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

This listview is not rendered correctly. I just see blue hyperlinks.

[image: Listview issie]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK so the trick was to add the refresh at the bottom of the userdetailspanel part.

So, after the UL, add:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
       $('#commandlist').listview().listview('refresh');
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

After appending items dynamically into panel, call `.trigger('pagecreate');`

```js
$('[data-role=page]').trigger('pagecreate');
```

or

```js
$.mobile.activePage.trigger('pagecreate');
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/PRC8W/)** - jQM 1.3.2 and below

---

For jQuery Mobile v 1.4, it is different

```js
$('.target').trigger('create')
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/5xCg4/)** - jQM v 1.4 Aplha

Comment: I like your demo but for me it does not work. I have a slightly different scenario. I open the panel with a dynamic PHP page. On it is a static listview. This listview does not render correctly.

Comment: I added an image of the issue. here you see a list but it is not rendered correctly

Comment: @CoenDamen `$.mobile.activePage.trigger('pagecreate');` didn't work? I'm not sure whether this will work `$('#commandlist').listview()` or `$('#commandlist').listview().listview('refresh')`.

Comment: in _user.php_ you only have listview html code or other code? @CoenDamen

Comment: I have other code (php and javascript) but there are no issues with this code, no errors and the code is reused from working code (I used to have a separate user.php page but now I want to use a Panel instead

Comment: @CoenDamen are you sure that jq or jqm aren't loaded again by .php file?

Comment: yes, the userdetailspanel.php is just using html without head, body etc

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36478/discussion-between-omar-and-coen-damen)